# Why does the Function Module name of a Smartform change (sometimes)?

Tags: forms, code-generation, abap, sap-smart-forms

Not really critical question, but i'm curious

I am working on a form and sometimes the generated function name is `/1BCDWB/SF00000473`, and sometimes `/1BCDWB/SF00000472`. This goes back and forth.

Does anyone know what's the idea behind this? Cuz i'm quite sure it's not a bug (or i might be wrong on that).

Comment: check this out, trying to get a SAP stack exchange started http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41621/sap-systems-applications-and-products

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a bug. You always have to use `SSF_FUNCTION_MODULE_NAME` to determine the actual function module name and call it dynamically using `CALL FUNCTION l_function_module`.

Comment: yeah, i know :P... but do we perhaps have some information from the kernel developers on why those numbers aren't constant at least in 1 client...or smth ? :) - thx!

Comment: The name of the function module should be stable (generated using the information in the table `STXFADMI`) - unless you're messing around with the contents of that table...

Comment: so in order to find out what's happening i should see who or what's modifying that table. got it :) thx.

Answer (score 1):

Smartform FMs are tracked by internal numbering and thats saved in the table STXFADMI. You would always notice the different number in Development System if you have deleted any existing Form. Similarly, you would also notice the different number in your Quality system based on the sequence the forms are imported in QAS and the forms as well (as test forms are not migrated to QAS.

Similar behavior is also true for Adobe Form generated FMs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that every smartform has a different interface and hence the automatically generated function module needs to have different import parameters.

Due to this reason the 'SSF*' FMs generate a FM specific for your smartform. The name of the 'generated' FM changes when you migrate from one system to another. And that's the reason why you should use a variable while calling the 'generated' fm and not hardcode it.

The same goes with Adobe form as someone has rightly said in this thread.

Comment: i'm not moving the form to another system. same system, activate once, gives me one name, activate a second time, gives me another name